# I can't access/find my exports when using my npm package

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, bundle, npm-package

I am currently working on a web app using next js and I want to import an npm package I wrote a few months ago but the import does not work because my imports are undefined. The package only contains an bundle.js and I wonder if this could be the cause.

This package is written in Typescript and transpiled into Javascript using Webpack and ts-loader.
All my exports are like `export default foo` or `export foo`. I have 2 objects exported in this package **Patient** and **Doctor**.

Here is how I have been trying to import them

```js
import SkopAPI from "skop-api"
```

I get this error when I try to use the package after this import.
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnAca.png)

or

```js
import {Patient} from "skop-api"
```

or again

```js
import Patient from "skop-api"
```

The error is different in this case [Screenshot of the 2nd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHZIY.png)

**This is my index.js file**

```js
import Doctor from './Doctor';
import Patient from './Patient';


export {Doctor, Patient};
```

**Here is the npm package webpack configuration**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  mode: 'development',
  target: "web",
    resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts','.js'],
  },
    module: {
        rules: [{
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: [
              'ts-loader',
              ]
        }],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'SkopAPI.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'demo'),
        library:{
            name: 'SkopAPI',
            type: 'umd',
        },
        globalObject: 'this',
    },
};
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "skop-api",
  "version": "1.1.8",
  "description": "API for the Skop",
  "main": "dist/SkopAPI.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "license": "CC BY-NC-ND 4.0",
  "keywords": [
    "api",
    "skop",
    "health api",
    "health",
    "WeMed"
  ],
  "author": "Ben Gregory",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/BenGregory23/SKOP-API-documentation.git"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/BenGregory23/SKOP-API-documentation#readme",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@opentok/client": "^2.22.1",
    "@tensorflow-models/blazeface": "^0.0.7",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl": "^3.18.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^3.18.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "base64url": "^3.0.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.1"
  }
}
```

---

I tried to add to my package the code in javascript and not only the bundle named SkopAPI.js but Patient and Doctor objects were still undefined.

**Code to reproduce**

```
import {Patient} from "skop-api"


export default foo(){
  const key = "key123";
  const room = 995;


  Patient.init(key, room);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, you have 2 differents projects (=2 package.json) :

- your skop-api project, exporting items
- your "client project", importing functions you describe in skop-api

How are you importing skop-api in your client ?

you should have something like this in your client's package.json

```
"dependencies":{
  "skop-api": "file:../path/to/skop-api/bundle.js"
  ...
}
```

Comment: In my client package.json the package is imported like so ` "skop-api": "^1.1.8"`. I installed it using npm. But I haven't tried to use it locally.

Comment: Ok, in your node_modules, are you able to see your skop-api package ? With an index.js file, bundled, exporting the component you are importing ?